# when opening new tabs, it should open the new tab diretly in jquery ui tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using jquery-UI for creating dynamic Tab panel.when i click on add Tab button, the new tab is get creating. but that tab panel is not opening directly. when click on that tab panel then only it is opening.

```
 $(function() {
var tabTitle = $( "#tab_title" ),
  tabContent = $( "#tab_content" ),
  tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
  tabCounter = 2;

var tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

// modal dialog init: custom buttons and a "close" callback resetting the form inside
var dialog = $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    Add: function() {
      addTab();
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  },
  close: function() {
    form[ 0 ].reset();
  }
});

// addTab form: calls addTab function on submit and closes the dialog
var form = dialog.find( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  addTab();
  dialog.dialog( "close" );
  event.preventDefault();
});

// actual addTab function: adds new tab using the input from the form above
function addTab() {
  var label = tabTitle.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter,
    id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
    li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, "#" + id ).replace( /#\{label\}/g, label ) ),
    tabContentHtml = tabContent.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter + " content.";

  tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
  tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>" );
  tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
  tabCounter++;
}

// addTab button: just opens the dialog
$( "#add_tab" )
  .button()
  .click(function() {
    dialog.dialog( "open" );
  });

// close icon: removing the tab on click
tabs.delegate( "span.ui-icon-close", "click", function() {
  var panelId = $( this ).closest( "li" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
  $( "#" + panelId ).remove();
  tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
});

tabs.bind( "keyup", function( event ) {
  if ( event.altKey && event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.BACKSPACE ) {
    var panelId = tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-active" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
    $( "#" + panelId ).remove();
    tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
  }
});
```

});

here is the url for jquery UI tab panel which i have used in my site [http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation].

how to directly open this newly added  tab?

Comment: there is two thing modify while open tab first tab class need to be added newly created tab and remove active class from currently active tab and apply css in tab-content such as disply:block when active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add following code in your addTab() function

```
    var lastChildIndex = $(".ui-tabs-nav").children().length - 1;
    $("div#tabs").tabs({active: lastChildIndex});
```

What this does is it gets the index of the last child of your tabs list (the one you just added) and sets it to active.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ujUu2/818/

EDIT: Seeing as you already have a tabCounter in your code you can use that as the index for setting the last tab active instead of the var lastChildIndex I proposed.

Comment: I have added above code. now it is working fine. Thanks